# UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection -- Best way to populate

Tags: uitableview, core-data, ios6

I'd like to show all the Data in a UITableView.  Sometimes the variables are NULL; at times some sections has only 1 row, while others can have 2 or 3 rows depending upon which variables have data.

Currently, in CellForRowAtIndexPath all the If and else if statements are beginning to look very messy.  i.e. for numberOfRowsInSection:

```
if (x!=NULL) return 1; else if (y!= NULL) return 2; else if ((x==NULL) && (y==NULL) return 3.
```

You can only imagine what cellForRowatIndexPath will look like.  Now try doing something similar for 15 attributes!  It's really nasty and creates a lot of room for error.

I know there is a way to do it with plist.  I have never done it with plist where it creates section dynamically based on NULL variables. If plist allows it, please advise?

Any other best practice approaches?  I'm all ears!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Here's what it does:

> You use a fetched results controller to efficiently manage the results returned from a Core Data fetch request to provide data for a UITableView object.

There's a great tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware of NSFetchedResultsController, but sometimes if certain attribues are null, some sections will be missing.  We want to show all the variables, but not if they are null, and nor if they are BOOLEANS.  How do I test for NULL variables with NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: Set your NSFetchedResultsController's data source (NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate) to only return the data you want to display back.  Don't include null / boolean data in your search if you don't want to display it.  You shouldn't have to do any additional filtering in your tableview delegate methods.  For example, just do `[[<#Fetched results controller#> sections] count]` in your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method.

Comment: When I'm fetching, I don't know which ones are NULL.  I don't necessarily need to display the BOOLEAN, but need to know if it's 1 or 0.  That will determine the number of sections and rows in the UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Best practice would be to use an `NSFetchedResultsController` as @Aaron suggests. If you set your predicate correctly, you won't get NULL values:

```
[request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(attributeThatMayBeNull != %@ AND booleanAttribute = %@)",[NSNull null],[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
```

Since you won't get the values you don't want, you won't have to check for them in your numberOfRows dataSource method. Just use the fetchedResults count.